# An infinity runner in Unity using Mobile Touch Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a 2D platformer with Unity and I have some problems with the scripts.

I'm using C# and I need a touch script that interacts with my jumping on the half right side of the screen or on the both side's of the screen. I've searched everywhere, but I can't find anything. If someone can help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: If this is a plain request for code, you're in the wrong place. We can help you with actual problems you're facing though. So if you have a problem with existing code, show it to us and explain clearly what the problem is.

Comment: This from the official unity site might help: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/infinite-runner

Answer (score 1):

2 simple ways I know:

Detect the area of touch when the player click/touch the screen:

C#

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{                
    var touchArea= new Rect(Screen.width/2, 0, Screen.width/2, Screen.height);
    if (touchArea.Contains(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y)))
    {
        Jump();
    }
}
```

Or create a giant invisible button that is half of the screen:

C#

```
var touchArea = new Rect(Screen.width/2, 0, Screen.width/2, Screen.height);

if (GUI.Button(touchArea, "", new GUIStyle()))
{
    Jump();
}
```

Note: Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) works for mouse clicks and touches (android/iphone).